# svg not displayed in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg file in my div1. Everything is working fine in chrome and edge but in Firefox the svg file disappears. I found out that if I delete the float for div1 (`.div1 {float:left}`) the svg is displayed in Firefox but of course my design is off. Any tips?

Edit: I need the float:left so my website layout stays the same.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k110grkt/)

Comment: Could you show us some of your code please?

Comment: I've added the fiddle. If you open it in mozilla the should be no pic

Comment: Can't repro FF43 on osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it (i think) by removing the div and img tag around the SVG and call the svg directly in CSS.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k110grkt/3/

```
svg {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Almost working, now the svg is going out of div0. That's why the img tag was there

Comment: Try giving the svg width:100%; then

Comment: For me it is working in the fiddle. You have an link to your page?

Comment: sorry it's on localhost

Comment: idk what the issue was but I got it to work, thanks!